# using forEach inside a string

Tags: javascript, node.js, commonjs

Im trying to use fs to make a Command-Handler for ESM(ECMAScript) because you can't use fs in ESM i have 2 js enviornments, one with ESM and one with Node.js the Node env is only there so it reads all file names of a folder and uses the names to import and export them inside a file that the other env uses. I allready have it so the names get stored inside a const in the node env but when i try to write them with fs it gives me an error, and when i try to log the string it says undefined

```js
const fs = require("fs")
const commands = []

try {
    fs.unlinkSync("./scripts/modules/commands.js")
    console.log('\x1b[32m File Deleted Succesfully \x1b[0m')
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}

try {
    fs.openSync("./scripts/modules/commands.js", 'w')
    console.log('\x1b[32m Created File Successfully')
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}

try {
    const cCommands = fs.readdirSync("./scripts/modules/commands/").filter(file => file.endsWith('.js'));
    for (const file of cCommands) {
        const name = file.replace(".js", "")
        commands.push(name)
    }
    console.log('\x1b[32m Pushed all Files Successfully \x1b[0m\n')
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}

// This outputs => 'ping' as a string
console.log(`${commands}`)

// This outputs => undefinedexport const commands = {undefined}; but should output => import {ping} from './commands/ping'; export const commands = {ping:ping};
console.log(`${commands.forEach(command => `import {${command}} from './commands/${command}';`)}export const commands = {${commands.forEach(command => `${command}:${command},`)}};`)

try {
    const cmdString = `${commands.forEach(command => `import {${command}} from './commands/${command}';`)}export const commands = {${commands.forEach(command => `${command}:${command},`)}};`
    const jsonString = JSON.stringify(cmdString);
    fs.writeFile("./scripts/modules/commands.js", jsonString)
    console.log(jsonString)
    console.log('\x1b[32m Send all Commands Successfully \x1b[0m')
} catch (e) {
    console.error(e)
}
```

Edit: Changed all .forEach() functions to .map() now this error accures => TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Comment: ForEach doesn’t return anything.  Try map.

Comment: Thanks, now that works but the fourth try{}catch(e){} throws this error => TypeError [ERR_INVALID_ARG_TYPE]: The "cb" argument must be of type function. Received undefined

Answer (score -1):

To fix this error just use fs.writeFileSync instead of fs.writeFile

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).